# Enumerate through reverse ordered array with powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, reverse, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate through a basic array, ordered alphabetically in reverse.

If I sort descending, then it shows in the console as I require. But the sorting doesn't 'stick' to the array when I iterate.

```
$symbols = @("Banana","Orange","Apple","Mango","Strawberry")

$symbols | Sort -Descending

write-host ""

foreach ($symbol in $symbols) {
    write-host $symbol
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks, Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pipe to sort doesn't manipulate the actual object, only a representation of it. To actually alter the object you need to assign to it with an `=`-sign.

```
$symbols = $symbols | Sort -Descending
```